# Solr server not starting on Windows

Tags: solr

Solr version 8.5.1

My solr is not starting anymore. I use `solr start` command to start the Solr. Every time I run this command I see the following error

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: JVM cannot use large page memory because it does not have enough privilege to lock pages in memory.
Waiting up to 30 to see Solr running on port 8983

ERROR: Solr at http://localhost:8983/solr did not come online within 30 seconds!
```

There is no error in the log files. But connecting to Solr is failing. This was working earlier.

Could someone please help me to troubleshoot the issue?

Comment: There should be some error in logs files. Check in SOLRDIR/<server>/logs

Comment: There are no errors. But some warning are there. 2020-05-14 07:01:24.397 WARN  (main) [   ] o.e.j.u.s.S.config Trusting all certificates configured for Client@60859f5a[provider=null,keyStore=null,trustStore=null]

Comment: There should be some logs available if Solr is trying to start and eventually not starting.

Comment: Following is directory structure and check logs directory https://ibb.co/DwR95ZD

Comment: Nothing that I could find. Please see the last lines from my solr.log file https://pastiebin.com/5ebd62fb5d466 Contents of solr-8983-console.log https://pastiebin.com/5ebd6355a9070

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the issue is. Even though the message indicated that the server did not start in 30 seconds, it started after some time.

I closed the console window as the server was running in the background and it killed the server. The server is up as long as I keep the command window that I used to start the server.